# ollydbg Plugins

Tags: reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I was going through lena's tutorial and now I gotta use some plugin, but it doesn't seem to work, (Lena's 2nd tutorial), I created a "plugins" folder and copied the files to that directory, but it's still not working, I was searching in google for an answer for like an hour, and haven't found any solution for that.
Anyone has succeed putting that plugin?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use OllyDbg v1.10 ? Because the current 2.01 was not supporting plugins until alpha4, and is not backward compatible with the existing plugins for 1.10.

Also, did you set the plugins folder in ollydbg settings ? Look in Options / Appearance / Directories tab page.

Comment: I am using OllyDBG v1.10, and according to your instructions, I have set the plugins directory as you said. and after trying to run OllyDbg I'm getting the following excpetion: ""The application has failed to start because immunitydebugger.exe was not found. Re-installing the applications may fix this problem""

Comment: NVM, It's working, I had to navigate the plugins directory to the plugin folder itself and not the one I created -_- Thanks!